# How to include existing tables into MVC5 IdentityModeld.cs ApplicationDbContext and disable migrations?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Bellow my MVC5 App IdentityModeld.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
}

//public class ApplicationDbContext : 
//IdentityDbContext<User, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin, Role, UserRole> {
//original: http://www.briankeating.net/?tag=/IdentityDbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {
        //Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
        //Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        //modelBuilder.Ignore<Staff>();
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    // dublicate from another DbContext
    //public DbSet<Staff> Person { get; set; }
}
```

Commented lines cause error:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created...

I don't need migrations. There are no changes in my database or models. Can I add to existing ApplicationDbContext existing table from database as is?
There is no __MigrationHistory table in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the shema stored "inside EF" to the current one by adding an empty migration.
Execute the following in the Package Manager Console:

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

This should create a new migration with the updated shema for EF, but an empty `Up` and `Down` method.

Comment: I get: No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'App'. (In Visual Studio you can use the **Enable-Migrations** command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).
Interesting is that my intension would disable migration at all